# Deep filter objects in javascript array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

From the following code below I need to return only the objects that have `meta.menu` in them while preserving the structure.

So in the case below, only the object with `"panel.users.view"` would get removed. I've tried making a recursive function to traverse it but I can't figure out how to infinitely traverse it because there could be more objects. I don't know how many levels deep a routes object can get.

I've also looked through **lodash** and **collect.js** to see if there were functions that could be used for this but I'm unable to find a solution on my own.

Would greatly appreciate the help, many thanks!

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/panel",
        name: "panel",
        redirect: { name: "panel.dashboard" },
        component: {},
        children: [
            {
                path: "/dashboard",
                name: "panel.dashboard",
                component: {},
                meta: {
                    menu: "main"
                },
            },
            {
                path: "/users",
                name: "panel.users",
                redirect: { name: "panel.dashboard" },
                component: {},
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "list",
                        name: "panel.users.list",
                        component: {},
                        meta: {
                            menu: "main"
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        path: "view/:user_id",
                        name: "panel.users.view",
                        component: {},
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
];
```

Comment: Hello. Your "panel.users" path , haven't meta.menu. So should all of it be completely removed with children?

Comment: Hi @ali.rezaie, thanks for taking the time to look into this. No, I want to preserve it if it has children. In this case, only the object with the name "panel.users.view" would get removed.

Comment: *From the following code below I need to return only the objects that have meta.menu in them while preserving the structure* - this will give `[]`. You may want to reconsider the presence of `meta.menu` in parent routes because otherwise you have to include them retroactively if their children are main, this certainly doesn't make things easier.  What did you try? Since you're new to SO, you may want to know 'write the code for me' questions that show no efforts aren't well-received.

Answer (score -2):

You could imagine a recursive function which would look something like.

```
const res = [];
function findMeta(rs) {
  rs.forEach(r => {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(r)) {
        //console.log(`${key}`, value);
                if(key === "children") findMeta(value);
                if(key === "meta") res.push(r);
      }
  })
  return res;
}
```

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/panel",
        name: "panel",
        redirect: { name: "panel.dashboard" },
        component: {},
        children: [
            {
                path: "/dashboard",
                name: "panel.dashboard",
                component: {},
                meta: {
                    menu: "main"
                },
            },
            {
                path: "/users",
                name: "panel.users",
                redirect: { name: "panel.dashboard" },
                component: {},
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "list",
                        name: "panel.users.list",
                        component: {},
                        meta: {
                            menu: "main"
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        path: "view/:user_id",
                        name: "panel.users.view",
                        component: {},
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
];

const res = [];
function findMeta(rs) {
  rs.forEach(r => {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(r)) {
        //console.log(`${key}`, value);
    if(key === "children") findMeta(value);
    if(key === "meta") res.push(r);
      }
  })
  return res;
}

console.log(findMeta(routes))
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for taking the time to write this. I have a small issue with it though, this solution results in `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: @user12922812 Okay sorry I did it without really testing here is a working solution.