# Code review: Deep filter array of objects concisely in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I've been trying to wrap my head around filtering arrays of objects for a while now, but I can't seem to really get a hang on it. Although I usually have working code in the end, it just doesn't look like elegant code to me. So, I'd appreciate a code review and some hints very much!

*Example:*
I'm currently working on this example for an online shop where I need to retrieve product details out of an array of objects based on an id.

This is my helper function:

```
function getItemDetails(id) {
        var getCategory = shelf.filter(obj => obj.articleList.some(cat => cat.id === id));
        var getArticleList = getCategory[0].articleList;
        var getItem = getArticleList.filter(item => item.id == id);
        return getItem 
}
```

*Steps:* In a first step, I tried to filter the `shelf` array, but it would return the entire array `articleList` of the corresponding item.

So, I filtered the result again with the same criteria and *it works*, but it just looks awfully redundant to me.

This is an example of the data:

```
const shelf = [{
    "categoryPrice": "2",
    "categoryTitle": "Flyer",
    "articleList": [{
        "id": "1",
        "articleTitle": "Green",
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "articleTitle": "Blue",
    }],
}, {
    "categoryPrice": "3",
    "categoryTitle": "Post card",
    "articleList": [{
        "id": "3",
        "articleTitle": "Purple"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "articleTitle": "Yellow",
    }]
}]
```

I checked various questions here, including:

- [Vue/Javascript filter in deep object inside object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619712/vue-javascript-filter-in-deep-object-inside-object-array)
- [Deep filter objects in javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292441/deep-filter-objects-in-javascript-array)

But none of them provide an easier, more concise solution, in my opinion. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How often do you filter, do you want your code optimized for (search time) performance or memory (no helper objects)?

Comment: I use this helper function all over the template to retrieve article names, prices, etc. - quite often I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a better fit for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) but if the question is just 'How to make this more concise' I would suggest something like following:

```js
const shelf = [{
  "categoryPrice": "2",
  "categoryTitle": "Flyer",
  "articleList": [{
    "id": "1",
    "articleTitle": "Green",
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "articleTitle": "Blue",
  }],
}, {
  "categoryPrice": "3",
  "categoryTitle": "Post card",
  "articleList": [{
    "id": "3",
    "articleTitle": "Purple"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "articleTitle": "Yellow",
  }]
}]

const findItem = function(shelves, id) {
  return shelves.flatMap((shelf) => shelf.articleList).find((article) => article.id == id) || null;
}

console.log(findItem(shelf, 1));
console.log(findItem(shelf, 3));
```

The above example concatenate all the list of articles and then searches that array for the article with the supplied ID.

Performance wise? Not the best, but you asked for something concise and this is about as concise as one can hope for with the given data structure.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! Just out of curiosity, what would you suggest performance wise? Thanks also for the hint with https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - I will keep it in mind for next time!

Comment: Performance wise the best thing would probably be to have all the articles in a lookup table. But given how the data structure in the example is, it is what it is. It might be faster to use nested loops rather than first concatenating all article arrays but it would have to benchmarked to know for sure.

Comment: @JimNilsson Performance wise, it will be on par after the first search through... Every search after the first is better, but on the other hand... it will use more memory... see my answer

Answer (score 3):

This code is O(1), which means that lookup per `article.id` is constant. It will however use more memory. To conserve memory, I used `WeakMap`, as long as you use the same `shelf` variable, it will not recompute it. But once you replace it, it will also perish from the cache.

```js
const shelf = [{
  "categoryPrice": "2",
  "categoryTitle": "Flyer",
  "articleList": [{
    "id": "1",
    "articleTitle": "Green",
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "articleTitle": "Blue",
  }, {
    "id": "3",  //  Added
    "articleTitle": "Violet",
  }],
}, {
  "categoryPrice": "3",
  "categoryTitle": "Post card",
  "articleList": [{
    "id": "3",
    "articleTitle": "Purple"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "articleTitle": "Yellow",
  }],
}];

const findItems = function(shelves, id) {
  if (!findItems._map) {
    // Create computation cache holder
    // Weak map will make sure, that if the object is disposed, it can be garbage collected, with it will be gone its cache too! (That is awsome!)
    findItems._map = new WeakMap();
  }
  if (!findItems._map.has(shelves)) {
    // For every shelves object, we will create a new Map containing all mapped values.
    const map = new Map();
    findItems._map.set(shelves, map);
    shelves.forEach(shelf => {
      shelf.articleList.forEach(article => {
        if (!map.has(article.id)) {
          // If list is not yet created create it with the article
          return map.set(article.id, [ article ]);
        }
        
        // If it exists, add to it
        map.get(article.id).push(article);
      });
    });
  }

  return findItems._map.get(shelves).get(id);
}

console.log(findItems(shelf, "1"));
console.log(findItems(shelf, "3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with looping twice. Once for the outer array and once for the articleList array

```js
const findItem = (id) =>
    shelf.reduce((acc, current) => {
        const found = current.articleList.find((x) => x.id === id);
        if (found) return [...acc, found];
        return acc;
    }, []);
```